# CodeIgniter form_open not hitting controller

Tags: codeigniter, .htaccess, routes, codeigniter-2

Hi all I am new to CodeIgniter framework. I tried to develop a page which contains a form.

#### Here is the view

```
<?php echo form_open('Site/check');?>

User Name: <?php   echo form_input(array('id'=>'Username' ,'name'=>'username' ,'class="input-medium " ')); ?> 
Add User:<?php   echo form_submit('submit','Add User','class="btn btn-primary"');?> 
<?php echo  form_close();?>
```

#### This is the controller

```
<?php class Site extends CI_Controller{

  function login() {
      $data['records']="BHOOM!!!";
      $this->load->view('login',$data);
  }

  function check() {
     $this->load->view('showmessage');
  }

}
?>
```

The showmessage is a PHP page with a hello in `<h1>` tags.
I already googled and searched for similar issues, but I didn't get any resolution

The base url is  `localhost/ci/index.php`

#### Error

Unable to load the requested file: `showmessage.php`

#### .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|js|css|img\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: It already have a form_close() also in it. but i am not able to include it in the question. I used pre and code.. ctrl+k also.

Comment: Try with: site/check (lowercase 's').

Comment: What error is shown? What is it, exactly, doesn't work?

Comment: where have u placed 'showmessage' file i.e. Folder structure?

Comment: @nevermind best is to use `base_url()`, in this example `base_url('site/check')`, if "nice url" is turned on.

Comment: @Kyslik, you are right. Actually, i always use .htaccess for removing 'index.php' from urls, and leave base_url and index_page blank in application config file-> best way to avoid issues like this...

Comment: @LolCoder: showmessage is placed under ci/application/view/showmessage.php

Comment: @nevermind i tried lowercase and base_url() which is localhost/ci/index.php

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html) is a tutorial straight from [EllisLab](http://ellislab.com/). Follow steps and you will get your form working.

The most common mistakes,

1. not loading `form` helper
2. `htaccess.` is set wrong, or paths are wrong (capital letters etc.).
3. `config.php` is not set properly
4. not passing data to view (`$this->load->view('some_view', $data);`

Hence you did not provide us error message if one exists there is no possible help from the community.

For more debug info please turn on codeigniters profiler (`$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);`), use PHPs native function `var_dump($variable);`.

Make sure [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) is set to `E_ALL` in your `index.php`

**edit**

Make sure your `/config/config.php`

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Index File
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Typically this will be your index.php file, unless you've renamed it to
| something else. If you are using mod_rewrite to remove the page set this
| variable so that it is blank.
|
*/
$config['index_page'] = "";
```

make your `.htaccess` this file should be located in root of your project eg. `/ci/.htaccess`

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /ci/

  # Reenable after getting ssl cert
  # RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

  # Removes access to the system folder by users
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  # When your application folder isn't in the system folder This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

  # Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file, such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the request to index.php
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks Kyslik, i have added the error and htaccess details. Reply: 1. form as well as url have been added in helper. 3. What i have to set in config? 4. I tried passing a variable and that also didn't work out.

Comment: take a look http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html to section `Adding Dynamic Data to the View` thats how to pass variables to view, but I am afraid you don't need this, in matter of question. Please provide us with proper question or error that causes your problem.

Comment: + please try load this page `localhost/ci/site/check` if it throws you `404 error`, look here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html and set up your codeigniter installation as tutorial shows you.

Comment: Thanks all, i deleted all files and created everything from scratch. And i restarted the wamp server and now everything looks fine. system is not redirecting correctly.

Answer (score 0):

just use this type of code for your trial

view

```
<?php 
echo form_open('controllet_name/method_name'); 
form_input(array('id'=>'Username' ,'name'=>'username' ,'class="input-medium " '));
form_close();
?>
```

controller

```
()
{
    $name=$this->input->post('username');
echo $name ;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your RewriteRule is wrong.
Try:
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /ci/index.php/$1 [L]